# Cumulative sum for each row of data for the same ID

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I have this data frame:

```
df=data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,2,5,NA),var=c("a","a","b","b","b","e","f"),value=c(1,1,0,1,0,0,1),cs=c(2,2,3,3,3,3,NA))
```

I want to calculate the sum of value for each group (id, var) and then the cumulative sum but I would like to have the cumulative sum to be displayed for each row of data, i.e., I don't want to summarized view of the data. I have included what my output should look like. This is what I have tried so far:

```
df%>%arrange(id,var)%>%group_by(id,var)%>%mutate(cs=cumsum(value))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide your expected output.

Comment: Updated, provided as cs

Comment: Your `cs` is not a cumulative sum. For id=1, var=a, for example, it has value=1,1 but your cs is 2,2. A cumulative sum would be 1,2.

Comment: it is the cs per group, the cumsum for group id=1 var=a is 2. so cs is 2,2.

Comment: Ashti, *cumulative sum* means that the first result in that group is itself; the second result is the sum of the first value and the second value; the third result is the sum of the first through the third values; etc through the length of that group.

Comment: @r2evans, that is what I'm looking for. for group id=1, var=a, the sum of value is 2. And the csum should be 2 for the rows this group appears. for the next id=2, var=b, the sum of values are 1 but the csum is 3, so on and so forth. Does that make sense?

Comment: where is it different? I think I provided the right outcome

Comment: NO. You say "cumulative sum" and then say that all `cs` for a group will be the same value. *This is not right*. For the group id=2, var=b, the cumulative sum should be `c(0, 0+1, 0+1+0)` which means `c(0, 1, 1)`. Never 3. Your `cs` column isn't even a *sum* of `value`.

Comment: @r2evans I apologize for the terminology I used, I will go back and edit the question. I want to get the sum of value for each group ( id+var), and then the cumulative sum. I wasn't sure about the wording of the question- and I don't think im using cumsum in the wrong way here. I just want the cumsum to be displayed for every row of data.

Comment: @Ben, yep I did. Thank you, that works! I was hoping there was a way where I didn't have to use a join but I think yours works very well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that I think meets your expectations.

Would group by `id` and calculate the sum of `value` for each `id` via `summarise`.

You can then add your cumulative sum column with `mutate`. Based on your comments, I included an `ifelse` so that if `id` was `NA`, it would not provide a cumulative sum, but instead be given `NA`.

Finally, to combine your cumulative sum data with your original dataset, you would need to join the two tables.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(value)) %>%
  mutate(cs=ifelse(is.na(id), NA, cumsum(sum))) %>%
  left_join(df)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
     id   sum    cs var   value
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
1     1     2     2 a         1
2     1     2     2 a         1
3     2     1     3 b         0
4     2     1     3 b         1
5     2     1     3 b         0
6     5     0     3 e         0
7    NA     1    NA f         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate cumulative sum over all values, even if `id` is `NA`, then alter final `cs` to `NA` if  `id` is `NA`

```
df %>% 
  arrange(id, var) %>% 
  mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
  group_by(id, var) %>% 
  mutate(cs = max(ifelse(!is.na(id), cs, NA))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**OR**, Exclude rows where `id` is `NA` when calculating cumulative sum

```
df %>% 
  arrange(id, var) %>% 
  mutate(cs = cumsum(ifelse(!is.na(id), value, 0))) %>%
  group_by(id, var) %>% 
  mutate(cs = max(ifelse(!is.na(id), cs, NA))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

For your data, both return similar result

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#      id var   value    cs
#   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 a         1     2
# 2     1 a         1     2
# 3     2 b         0     3
# 4     2 b         1     3
# 5     2 b         0     3
# 6     5 e         0     3
# 7    NA f         1     4
```

Comment: NA should not have a cs.

Comment: Ashti, please put arbitrary (not-obvious) constraints like that into your question.